# Creating .map file with mapfilewriter plugin for osmosis

Tags: android

I tried to make a .map file to use it in my android application. My point is to show map on screen with help of mapsforge library. Library requires a .map file. The problem is generating it with osmosis mapfilewriter plugin. When I use command

```
./osmosis --rx file=/home/user/poland.osm --mw file=result.map bbox=51.09,16.9,51.14,17
```

I get

```
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-rx failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried using another order of arguments but it also doesn't work. I also tried using `-Xmx1200m` option to increase javas heap memory but usage of memory was this same and didn't help.

I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the parameter [`type=hd`](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter#Basic_Options).

The `type` parameter has two options `ram` and `hd`. Although I don't see that the documentation doesn't explicitly state what hd means, I would guess it means "hard disk", meaning it would offload data to disk, rather than keeping it all in memory.

The resulting command would be then:

```
./osmosis --rx file=/home/user/poland.osm --mw file=result.map bbox=51.09,16.9,51.14,17 type=hd
```

Comment: Indeed. This will solve most memory issues for larger maps - at the cost of slowing down the processing; in my experience, the disk-based temporary storage is somewhat larger than a memory-based one, so be sure to have enough free space.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough memory, you need to tell Java about it (it will only use a limited amount otherwise); but this is not an argument passed directly to osmosis.

On Windows, you can follow [this advice given by Emilie Laffray on the OSM-dev list](http://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/dev/2009-February/014116.html):

> In osmosis.bat is the following line... REM # JAVACMD_OPTIONS - The
>   options to append to the java command, typically used to modify jvm
>   settings such as max memory.
>
> so, either modify osmosis.bat or, create a new file called osmosis.bat
>   in the all users profile directory or your profile directory, to
>   include a 'set JAVACMD_OPTIONS = -Xmx1024M' line (to set maximum
>   memory usage to 1GB, if you have enough RAM)...

On Linux (and I'd assume Mac OS X also), you can create the file `~/.osmosis`
containing the line

```
JAVACMD_OPTIONS=-Xmx1024M
```

which will be loaded by osmosis on startup. Note that both examples above use the value `1024M`, i.e. you're giving Java access to 1024 MB of RAM - you could use a different value depending on your system.

Comment: Do you know if this could apply to other Java software by default? E.g.: let's say instead of osmosis (Java based program) we have xyz (which is Java based too). Creating a ~/.xyz file with the content described above, would it automatically take this setting?